# How to register a package of Formatters in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

let's say I have 200 formatters contained in one package. How can I register a package of formatters instead of doing this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="formatters">
        <set>
           <ref bean="MyFormatter1" />
           <ref bean="MyFormatter2" />
           ...
           <ref bean="MyFormatter200" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use java configuration for that:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.Formatter;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        for (Formatter formatter : collectFormatters()) {
            registry.addFormatter(formatter);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to implement `collectFormatters` method. I don't know the details of your application so there maybe many different ways to do it:

1) you could put `@Component` annotation to all formatters, add this package to autoscanning, so Spring will initialize them and add to the application context. After that you can just inject them like this: `@Resource List<Formatter> formatters`.

2) you could write some logic for inspecting the package by yourself (I suggest to look at how Spring doing this).